# How to implement solr search for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr

I have sunspot_rails in my gemfile for my rails app.  When I deploy, I use heroku.  I find that when I do, I get charged for a heroku add-on that enables this to work.  When I remove the add-on, search doesn't work anymore.

Is it possible to use this gem without paying for the add-on or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think you can get around the fact that they are charging for it as an add on. https://addons.heroku.com/websolr

Comment: @jfvanderwalt So there's no way to include solr without paying for it in production?

Comment: no, if you want to use Heroku and Websolr you pay for the addon.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need a special Heroku 'add-on' for using sunspot_rails as opposed to many other gems, is because sunspot relies on Solr, which is a actually *a separate Java application* which needs to be run on your server. Heroku is charging you for running that distinct Solr application. If you weren't on Heroku, you could set up your own Solr instance on your server.